# Flutter Supabase - Join Tables

Tags: postgresql, flutter, relational-database, supabase, supabase-database

I have 2 tables

1. Department(id, department_name)
2. Programs(id, program_name, department_id)

[image: Data flow diagram]

dept_id in *Programs* is the foreign key from *Department* table

I want to join *department_id* in *Program* table and *id* in *Department* table
I'm unable to do it in Flutter supabase `supabase_flutter: ^0.2.12`. Please help me out
Thanks

Edit:
I want to perform this action from the front end. (Flutter)

```
CREATE TABLE Departments (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Programs (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  dept_id INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY (dept_id) references Departments(id)
);

INSERT INTO Departments VALUES (1, 'DEPT_A');
INSERT INTO Departments VALUES (2, 'DEPT_B');
INSERT INTO Programs VALUES (1, 'PROG_A', 1);
INSERT INTO Programs VALUES (2, 'PROG_B', 1);
INSERT INTO Programs VALUES (3, 'PROG_C', 2);
INSERT INTO Programs VALUES (4, 'PROG_D', 2);

SELECT Departments.name, Departments.id, Programs.name, Programs.id
FROM Departments 
INNER JOIN Programs
ON Departments.id = Programs.dept_id;
```

Comment: "I'm unable ..." Then what are you able to do? (Perhaps you can query each table separately?) What have you tried for joining? (Did you get an error rejection of some kind?)

Comment: Hi @AntC, I couldn't find any documentation to join tables in **supabase_flutter: ^0.2.12** or in the supabase website.
I could query each table separately but I want to join the tables and query the database as it is relational database

Answer (score 1):

If your database has relationships, you can query related tables too.

```
final res = await supabase
  .from('countries')
  .select('''
    name,
    cities (
      name
    )
  ''')
  .execute();
```

This is directly from the docs: [Supabase Dart Docs](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/dart/select)

Answer (score 1):

For example, you have two tables "users" and "clothes".

And you have in "users" column "clothe_id" as forieng key for column "id" in "clothes".

You can use this code to get tables.

```
final List data = await AppSupabase.client
        .from('users')
        .select('name, clothes!users_clothe_id_fkey!inner(*)')
        .eq('name', 'Admin');

// [{name: Admin, clothes: {id: 1, title: Costume, level: 4, ...}}]
```

Also you can filter, for example, by column "level" in "clothes":

```
final List data = await AppSupabase.client
        .from('users')
        .select('name, clothes!users_clothe_id_fkey!left(level)')
        .gte('clothes.level', 2);

//[{name: Jane, clothes: null}, {name: Admin, clothes: {level: 4}}] 


final newList = data
        .where((element) => element['clothes'] != null)
        .toList();

//[{name: Admin, clothes: {level: 4}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set up a foreign key relation in supabase from within your table editor by pressing edit on the column you want to add one to.

[image]

Comment: Hi KeoooDev, thanks for responding. I have done that, but from the front-end how to join two tables and get the data?